# How do I run an animated graph from an opencv while loop?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I've been working on this for weeks now and I'm sure it is due to my lack of basic python knowledge. I need to animate something using the Matplotlib `FuncAnimation` function. So far I am able to generate my y values into a list by using a while loop(these values fluctuate up and down, which should create a graph that looks similar to a heart monitor when plotted with frames on the x axis).

I always seem to run into two major problems:

1) I can never access the data created from the while loop and use it for my graph.

2) I can never plot the graph with the `FuncAnimation` function while simultaneously running the opencv while loop.

Could someone please take the time to look over my current code and point out the major flaws, I'm sure it will look pretty messy, but I don't know where to begin anymore to make this thing work. I'm about to start from the beginning.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


# Parameters
x_len = 200         # Number of points to display
y_range = [10, 40]  # Range of possible Y values to display

# Create figure for plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = list(range(0, 200))
ys = [0] * x_len
ax.set_ylim(y_range)

# Create a blank line. We will update the line in animate
line, = ax.plot(xs, ys)

def animate(i, ys):
    ys.append(avg)
    ys = ys[-x_len:]
    line.set_ydata(ys)
    return line,

def data_gen():
    average = (np.average(difference))
    average_int = int(average)
    return average_int

def initialize_camera(cap):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    return frame

#Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(ys,), interval=50, blit=True)

plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    first_frame = initialize_camera(cap)
    while cap.isOpened():

        ret, frame = cap.read( )

        difference = cv2.absdiff(first_frame, frame)

        _, difference = cv2.threshold(difference, 18, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        avg = data_gen()

        cv2.imshow('first frame', first_frame)
        cv2.imshow('Original', frame)
        cv2.imshow('difference', difference)



        print(avg)
        key = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
        if key == 27:
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print('End Stream')
```

The while loop that creates all the data is in the if statement `if __name__ == '__main__':`, this needs to run and create my y values. Then I want to plot it with a static x axis of 200 points. I need to use the `FuncAnimation` function and blitting in order to have enough FPS to accurately read the data.

Comment: I don't think it is wise to mix a while loop with FuncAnimation. Or more generally to try to run two loops at once. I suspect you either need to integrate the content of the while loop into the animating function, or the content of the animating function into the while loop.

Comment: What would you recommend the easiest to achieve for a beginner programmer? Also, would I have to take apart the animating function in order to do such a thing?